# How to Handle NoResumeHandler exception in Microsoft bot framework?

Tags: botframework

How to handle exception in chatbot using Microsoft Bot Framework. I am getting the exception below since I have given a wrong LUIS subscripion key but I would like to handle the exception and provide a custom message instead of the below one!

> NoResumeHandlerException: IDialog method execution finished with no resume handler specified through IDialogStack.

Here is the code follows of the MessageController..[image: exception message]

```
if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                //await Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new ContactOneDialog());

                //Implementation of typing indication
                //ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new System.Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
                //Activity isTypingReply = activity.CreateReply("Shuttlebot is typing...");
                //isTypingReply.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
                //await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(isTypingReply);

                logger.Debug("The User's local timeStamp is: " + activity.LocalTimestamp + "and service timeStamp is: " + activity.Timestamp);
                await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () =>
                new ExceptionHandlerDialog<object>(new ShuttleBusDialog(), displayException: true));
            }
            else
            {
                HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            }
```

Comment: Could you please post some code sample?

Comment: you should call `context.Done` function at the end of your dialog.

Comment: Please post the code of the ExceptionHandlerDialog